# Codeigniter route configuration doesn't work in my application

Tags: codeigniter

Am having three controller the first one is "sw" the second one is product and the third one is catalog controller. What happen is I created a route in my application such that any request to category which is the public function of catalog will be mapped as follows

```
$route['sw/product'] = "product";
$route['sw/product/catalog'] = "catalog";
$route['sw/product/catalog/category'] = "catalog/category";
```

but category as public function of catalog passes two parameter which are type and store so my next route should be like

```
$route['sw/product/catalog/category/(:any)'] = "catalog/category/(:any) ";
```

The problem is  the last route gives me bellow error

```
<h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>
<p>The page you requested was not found.</p>
```

And I have no idea why it is not working because it is supposed to work. Keep in mind I have no index.php in my url.

Answer (score 1):

`$route['sw/product/catalog/category/(:any)'] = "catalog/category/$1";`

If You need to pass more than one var to Your function use `$2, $3, ...` for example

`$route['sw/product/catalog/(:any)/(:any)'] = "catalog/category/$1/$2 ";`